# Difference between mysql datetime timestamp time

Tags: php, mysql, time

I want to get the current time when a login attempt is processed. I want to get the time retrieved in probably date and hour/min/sec.

I have a database with a field called `last_attempt`, which holds the date and time of the last login attempt.

Which of the types `Datetime`, `Timestamp`, `Time` or others should I use for the field? And also what method in PHP should I use?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: Ok, thx. What about php ? Should I combine `date()` and `time` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP time() is all you need. It returns the current time posted at the server in seconds from epoch january. (You'll store the result as a unsigned number most likely.)